# Can I create a new HTTP method in Express.js with Router Object?

Tags: node.js, express

I am currently studying with HTTP The Definitive Guide.
While studying HTTP messages in Chapter 3, I learned that there are extension methods such as LOCK, COPY, and MOVE.
I am wondering if there is any way to implement these extension methods in Express.js's router object too!

If possible, it could be called in the following way:

```js
const router = express.Router();

router.copy('/some/path', (req, res, next) => {});
router.move('/some/path', (req, res, next) => {});

// ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary:  `router.move(...)` and `router.copy(...)` should already work in Express with modern versions of nodejs.

In looking at the [Express router source code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/route.js), it uses the `methods` module to figure out what http methods are supported and uses those methods to determine what it should add to the `Router` object.  For recent versions of node.js, that module uses the constant `http.METHODS` and, if you look at what that constant is (in recent versions of nodejs), it shows this:

```
[
  'ACL',         'BIND',       'CHECKOUT',
  'CONNECT',     'COPY',       'DELETE',
  'GET',         'HEAD',       'LINK',
  'LOCK',        'M-SEARCH',   'MERGE',
  'MKACTIVITY',  'MKCALENDAR', 'MKCOL',
  'MOVE',        'NOTIFY',     'OPTIONS',
  'PATCH',       'POST',       'PROPFIND',
  'PROPPATCH',   'PURGE',      'PUT',
  'REBIND',      'REPORT',     'SEARCH',
  'SOURCE',      'SUBSCRIBE',  'TRACE',
  'UNBIND',      'UNLINK',     'UNLOCK',
  'UNSUBSCRIBE'
]
```

And, then if you look [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/route.js#L192) in the Express router source code, you see that it creates an Express method on the router for every one of those verbs.  So, it appears like the support is there for `router.move(...)` and `router.copy(...)`.  I'd suggest you try it.

I just verified that `router.move()` does indeed work in my own little test app using `http.request()` to send a MOVE command to my own little server.

Example:

```
const http = require('http');
console.log(http.METHODS);

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.move("/", function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('got MOVE verb');
    res.send("done");
});

app.listen(80, function() {
    // server is running now
    const req = http.request('http://localhost', {
        method: "MOVE"
    }, res => {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
        });
        res.on('end', () => {
            console.log('No more data in response.');
        });
    });
    req.on('error', (e) => {
        console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
    });

    // Write data to request body
    req.write("xxx");
    req.end();
});
```